# ¿Como mostrar un mensaje de error al ingresar datos en input usando Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, input

Estoy usando un `input` con diseño y animación de [Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) para ingresar datos, los cuales deben ser validados en tiempo de escritura y mostrar un mensaje de error o de correcto.

**No puedo hacer que muestre correctamente el color y mensaje de si esta bien o mal**

```js
document
    .getElementById('entrada')
    .addEventListener('input',validar);


function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('entrada').value,
        resultado = document.getElementById('help');

    patro2 = /^\w{3,5}\d{6}\w{3,4}$/;
    patron = /^\d{8}$/;
    if (patron.test(usuario)||patro2.test(usuario)) {
        resultado.innerText = "correcto";
        console.log('correcto');
    } else {
        resultado.innerText = "ERROR";
        console.log('error');
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="entrada" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="entrada">Entrada</label>
                <span  id="help" class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Ingrese datos</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué tomas en cuenta al escribir en tiempo real para saber si está bien o no y pintarlo de otro color, amigo?

Comment: @FernandoTorres uso `patro2` y `patron` para indicar si esta bien lo que se ingreso o no, si te refieres a que valores son validos, es: **12345678** o **qwer123456as6**

Comment: Sí vi, amigo, pero, mi pregunta es más bien, ¿eso qué valida? Ya que yo puedo interpretar algo erróneo en esa expresión regular, ¿qué esperas validar?

Comment: @FernandoTorres edite mi respuesta los datos validos son: **12345678** o **qwer123456as6**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si sea la forma mas optima, pero estudiando un poco el código que tiene **Materializecss** en el archivo **materialize.js** para validar el campo, lo que hice fue agregar y remover la **clase** encargada de aplicar el estilo cuando esta correcto o erróneo.

Quedando la funcion `validar()` de la siguiente manera

```
function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('entrada'),
        resultado = document.getElementById('help');

    patro2 = /^\w{3,5}\d{6}\w{3,4}$/;
    patron = /^\d{8}$/;
    if (patron.test(usuario.value)||patro2.test(usuario.value)) {
        usuario.classList.remove('invalid');
        usuario.classList.add('valid');
    } else {
        usuario.classList.remove('valid');
        usuario.classList.add('invalid');
    }

}
```

---

Si lo que se quiere es cambiar el texto a mostrar y no hacerlo desde el `html`, otra opcion seria agregar lo siguiente.

```
setAttribute('data-error','Mensaje personalizado')
```

**Quedando de la siguiente manera**

```
function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('entrada'),
        resultado = document.getElementById('help');

    patro2 = /^\w{3,5}\d{6}\w{3,4}$/;
    patron = /^\d{8}$/;
    if (patron.test(usuario.value)||patro2.test(usuario.value)) {
        usuario.classList.remove('invalid');
        usuario.classList.add('valid');
        resultado.setAttribute('data-success','Dato correcto');
    } else {
        usuario.classList.remove('valid');
        usuario.classList.add('invalid');
        resultado.setAttribute('data-error','Dato incorrecto');
    }

}
```

---

### Dando como resultado lo siguiente

```js
document
    .getElementById('entrada')
    .addEventListener('input',validar);


  function validar() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('entrada'),
        resultado = document.getElementById('help');

    patro2 = /^\w{3,5}\d{6}\w{3,4}$/;
    patron = /^\d{8}$/;
    if (patron.test(usuario.value)||patro2.test(usuario.value)) {
        usuario.classList.remove('invalid');
        usuario.classList.add('valid');
    } else {
        usuario.classList.remove('valid');
        usuario.classList.add('invalid');
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="entrada" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="entrada">Entrada</label>
                <span  id="help" class="helper-text" data-error="Dato no valido" data-success="Correcto">Ingrese datos</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: eso fue exactamente lo que hice cuando estaba revisando tu codigo , pero vi inconsistencias respecto al span que querias mostrar como mensaje , ya que en tu pregunta , aclarabas que tambien era el texto el que querias cambiar y materialize lo colocaba por defecto , por eso te dije que podias sobreescribir tu label , donde hagas todos esos cambios , tu mismo , la forma que aplicaste es valida siempre y cuando no te interese el titulo de los span respecto al error o exito

Comment: @DiegoAndresRojas claro llegar al mensaje es lo importante, y también lo pude hacer con **Js** pero al ser 2 textos predeterminados no vi la necesidad de hacerlo con **js** a si que aproveche lo que ya coloca **Materializecss**, usando `data-success` y `data-error`. edito mi respuesta para mostrar los mensajes que es a lo que se quería llegar.

Comment: dale bro , suerte con tu codigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Si tu te diriges a la pagina de documentación de [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) , podrás observar que para los campos de tipo texto , dicha validación no funciona de la misma manera que para por ejemplo un campo de tipo email , ya que dichos campos deben tener una configuración predeterminada para que funcionen con los `data-success` y `data-error` , dicho eso también cabe la pena resaltar que he trabajado algunas veces con materialize y he encontrado varias inconsistencias o "bugs" extraños, estuve una hora checkeando tu codigo de distintas formas , para tratar de enlazarlo con materialize, pero el codigo por debajo de materialize no permite hacer cambios que uno esperaria funcionaran , te recomiendo cambiar de forma para llegar al mismo objetivo , o hacerlo con materialize pero sobreescribir ese label para tu mismo implementar los colores que deseas de error y exito , mucha suerte :)

Comment: Gracias por intentar. Tienes razón hay **inconsistencias** y **bugs** en varios casos, pero por suerte llegue a una solución pasable, después de estudiar su código fuente un buen rato, logre aplicarlo a mi propia lógica e idea para dicho problema, he publicado una respuesta por si te sirve o alguien mas.

Comment: eso es lo importante Richard , que encuentres la solución , pero si vas a quedarte con la version de que no aparezca el span de error o correcto si no lo predeterminado por materialize , quisas deberias editar la parte donde dices No puedo hacer que muestre correctamente el color y `mensaje` de si esta bien o mal , suerte con tu codigo amigo :)

Comment: Gracias, en cuanto a la parte del texto que mencionas(_No puedo hacer que muestre correctamente el color y mensaje_), con la respuesta que coloque(editado recientemente), se aplica correctamente el **mensaje** y **color** de pendiendo de si esta bien o mal, pero en caso de que veas alguna mejora o sugerencia al código que ayude, agradecido estaré. Saludos.